# Split a list into positive and negative lists using c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have one list of positive and negative values, and I need to:

- sort them
- convert them to int, I am multiplying them by 100 :)
- split them into two lists
- take out the common value out, these should be +ve and -ve pair

e.g.

`input = 1.00,2.92,-2.92,3.00,7.56,-7.56,8.00, -100.93, -40.56 ......`

End goal:

```
listA = 1, 3, 8
listB = -4056, -10093
```

I am looking for suggestions for improving my below code, speed and accuracy both are important.

```
var results = new List<decimal>(input.Select(x => x*100 ));
results.Sort();
var listA = results.FindAll(x => ((decimal)x > 0));
var listB = results.FindAll(x => ((decimal)x < 0));
decimal[] FromA_NotIn_B = listA.Except(listB.Select(X => (X = X * -1))).ToArray();
decimal[] FromB_NotIn_A = listB.Except(listA.Select(X => (X = X * -1))).ToArray();
```

Comment: _split them into 2 lists_ do you mean list of -ve and list of +ve?

Comment: By common values you mean common absolute values?

Comment: this question is very unclear, please clarify

Comment: Reniuz yes, split 1 list into 2, 1 for positive values and one with -ve values

Comment: Hogan: what i mean by common values are + and -ve pair, e.g. +ve list has +2 and -ve list has -2 so the goal is to remove +2 and -2 from both of these list.

Comment: BrokenGlass: what would you like to know more, i am happy to help you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct in terms of accuracy (decimal does not loose precision when inverting its sign). Its speed can be improved surely by 20x by writing it with loops and doing a manual full outer merge join. However I would only recommend this if perf is critical cause this will explode code size by 5x.

Edit: A merge join means taking two sorted lists side-by-side and walking along both list in a way that equal elements can be found, even if there are excess elements in both arrays. This is a extension of the merge step in merge-sort. Full-outer means what it means in databases: Keep values that are only in one of the arrays.

The only requirement, sorted lists, is a given because you sort the results list.

Your code would work like this:

```
var results = new List<decimal>(input.Select(x => x*100 ));
results.Sort();
var listA = new List<decimal>();
var listB = new List<decimal>();

//now to the merge-join and fill listA and B
```

The merge-join will be complicated to implement but to get you startet here is an iterator-based version that I use in my project to to a join between two gigantic files that I could never load into memory but that are sorted.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MergeJoin_OneToOne<TLeft, TRight, TResult>(
        IEnumerable<TLeft> leftCollection,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightCollection,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, int> comparison,
        Func<TLeft, TResult> onlyLeftSelector,
        Func<TRight, TResult> onlyRightSelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> bothSelector)
    {
        return MergeJoin_OneToOne_Impl(leftCollection, rightCollection, comparison, onlyLeftSelector, onlyRightSelector, bothSelector);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TResult> MergeJoin_OneToOne_Impl<TLeft, TRight, TResult>(
        IEnumerable<TLeft> leftCollection,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightCollection,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, int> comparison,
        Func<TLeft, TResult> onlyLeftSelector,
        Func<TRight, TResult> onlyRightSelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> bothSelector)
    {
        if (leftCollection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("leftCollection");
        if (rightCollection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("rightCollection");
        if (comparison == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("comparison");
        if (onlyLeftSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("onlyLeftSelector");
        if (onlyRightSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("onlyRightSelector");
        if (bothSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bothSelector");

        using (var leftEnum = leftCollection.GetEnumerator())
        using (var rightEnum = rightCollection.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!leftEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                while (rightEnum.MoveNext()) yield return onlyRightSelector(rightEnum.Current);
                yield break;
            }

            if (!rightEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                do
                {
                    yield return onlyLeftSelector(leftEnum.Current);
                } while (leftEnum.MoveNext());
                yield break;
            }

            while (true)
            {
                int cmp = comparison(leftEnum.Current, rightEnum.Current);
                if (cmp == 0)
                {
                    yield return bothSelector(leftEnum.Current, rightEnum.Current);

                    if (!leftEnum.MoveNext())
                    {
                        while (rightEnum.MoveNext())
                        {
                            yield return onlyRightSelector(rightEnum.Current);
                        }
                        yield break;
                    }
                    if (!rightEnum.MoveNext())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            yield return onlyLeftSelector(leftEnum.Current);
                        } while (leftEnum.MoveNext());
                        yield break;
                    }
                }
                else if (cmp < 0)
                {
                    yield return onlyLeftSelector(leftEnum.Current);

                    if (!leftEnum.MoveNext())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            yield return onlyRightSelector(rightEnum.Current);
                        } while (rightEnum.MoveNext());
                        yield break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return onlyRightSelector(rightEnum.Current);

                    if (!rightEnum.MoveNext())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            yield return onlyLeftSelector(leftEnum.Current);
                        } while (leftEnum.MoveNext());
                        yield break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For performance reasons you specialize this function for `IList<decimal>` elements. Kick out the iterator stuff and use two ints to represent the current position in the list. While walking listA ignore elements that are lt 0 and the same for B.

The speed boost will come from multiple improvements: Object allocations are greatly reduced; The hashing operations performed by Except are gone; No lambdas and no indirections.

Comment: usr: I would like to get better performance from the code not worried about LoC, could you please clarify what u mean by "manual full outer merge join".

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this one P.S. i am looking at raw performance here, list i am going to work with will have 000's decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Works :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] input = { 1.00, 2.92, -2.92, 3.00, 7.56, -7.56, 8.00, -100.93, -40.56 };
        IEnumerable<int> intsWithouDuplicates = input.Where(d => !input.Contains(-d)).Select(d => (int)(d * 100)).OrderBy(i => i);
        var listA = intsWithouDuplicates.Where(i => i >= 0);
        var listB = intsWithouDuplicates.Where(i => i < 0);

        listA.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.WriteLine();
        listB.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll also have a look at this one P.S. i am looking at raw performance here, list i am going to work with will have 000's decimal.

Answer (score 0):

This should be much faster and remove duplicates reliably.
I skipped the “multiplication by 100” requirement because it does not contribute to the concept:

1) Sort by ABS value
2) Compare with top of stack, pop if match, push otherwise.
3) At the end of the process, stack contains only elements without a match

```
      decimal[] input = new decimal[] { -6, 1, 2, 3, -1, 2, 2, -2, 6, 7, -4, 4, -7, 8, -4 };
      Stack<decimal> st = new Stack<decimal>();

      IEnumerable<decimal> sorted = input.OrderBy(X => X > 0 ? X : -X);

      foreach (decimal item in sorted)
        if (st.Any() && st.Peek() == -item)
          st.Pop();
        else
          st.Push(item);

      decimal[] pos = st.Where(X => X >= 0).ToArray();
      decimal[] neg = st.Where(X => X < 0).ToArray();
```